# Getting the ID of a form field with php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which has an optgroup in it. As well as getting the value from the different options I also need to grab an ID from some of the fields and pass this into the script which does all the submitting.

I need to be able to pass the IDs with value of 1 and 13 into the script

I'm really struggling to do this so I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks

```
<optgroup>
  <option value="202" id="13">test value 1</option>
  <option value="202" id="1">test value 2</option>
</optgroup>
```

Additional information:

The form is for an availability checker that passes the values into a reservations system.

The value="202" is the parent resort with the id="13" and id="1" being sub resorts

I have ot pass both values into the system in the form of a string. The main retreat id needs to be passed as 202 and then i need to pass the sub resort id to select properties in that particular sub group

In an ideal world the 2 sub resorts would be given their own unique id but as this isnt possible due to restrictions with the system then i need to get an id for each sub resort and pass this

Thanks

Comment: Use `name=` instead of `id=`. (posted as an answer now)

Comment: tell us more about the use, there might be a better way

Comment: Note : a HTML ID should not be a simple number, as they must be unique values in the page (your can't have 2 `id="13"` in the same page). You'd better use `id="myvarname-13"` for instance.

Comment: @zdhickman : <options> never have names, only upper <select> has one.

Comment: Jason post your full option select element, so we can have a look at it, have you thought about using jQuery/javascript?

Answer (score 0):

in your form page you need something like:

```
<select name="selectTest" id="selectTest">
<optgroup>
  <option value="201">Description 1</option>
  <option value="202">Description 2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

and in your action page you can have the value as:

```
echo $_REQUEST[selectTest];
```

i am not clear on what will you do with ids once the form is submitted..??

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<select name="form">
<optgroup>
  <option value="201" id="13" name="13">Description 1</option>
  <option value="202" id="1" name="1">Description 2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST))
     var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your optgroup is in a `<select>` I guess ?

```
<optgroup>
  <option value="202-13" id="13">test value 1</option>
  <option value="202-1" id="1">test value 2</option>
</optgroup>
```

?

Comment: You still have the problem of the vals not being passed in the POST, as your using ID and not name

Comment: options never have names, only upper `<select>` has one : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/option . Here I only copy the value of the ID in the value, so that it can be passed in the POST.